# Does the Shockley Diode Equation hold in a dynamic circuit?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

Consider the following simple photodiode circuit:

[image]

I've created a real-life version of this circuit, and I've detected that $I$ is oscillating:
$$I(t)=I(t+\tau)\tag{$\tau\approx 0.016~\text{secs}$}$$
Since I'm certain that the incident light upon the diode is constant, I'm suspecting that the cause is an oscillating voltage $V_S$:
$$\text{Hypothesis}:~~V_S(t)=V(t+\tau_V)$$
However, based on the [Shockley diode equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Shockley_diode_equation) as given below,
$$\text{Shockley diode equation}:~~~~I=I_S(e^{V_D/(nV_T)}-1$$

$I$ is $\textbf{ independent}$ of $V_S$. However, the Shockley diode equation may just be a quasi-static approximation of the behavior of a pn-junction.

Based on your knowledge of the physics of a pn-junction, could the Shockley diode equation simply not hold if $V_S$ is oscillating sufficiently rapidly? If so, under what regimes?

Comment: Are you saying that the period of the observed oscillation is 0.016 seconds?  This corresponds to 60 Hz and may be an artifact (pickup) in your as-built circuit... (e.g. the light source has a 60 Hz component and is not "constant", or you have electrical pickup in your test equipment)

Comment: Yes - 63 Hz exactly, but 60 Hz is still plausible because of sources of error. What is electrical pickup?

Comment: Typically capacitive coupling between your circuit and a 60Hz source (e.g., the very power supply, DMM or oscilloscope you use to power/measure the circuit if said device is not filtered properly).  In your case, the photodiode might directly "see" 60Hz or in some cases 120Hz if you expose it to indoor/fluorescent lighting.  Turn the lights off, and use a battery-powered flashlight - do you still see oscillations?

Comment: Shockley's equation is good at least to mm-waves.

Comment: One would, normally, not operate a photodiode in conduction, to begin with. Photodiodes are usually operated in reverse at the highest voltage, at which the leakage current is not increasing, yet. Operation under a reverse voltage reduces the capacitance of the diode, which is the actual performance limiting parameter for detection of signals.

Comment: @CuriousOne its not obvious that he's doing that.  I know the schematic says otherwise but I think the schematic is actually wrong based on the description.  Based on the description, it is assumed that there's a (virtual) Vs in there somewhere causing his observed measurement, so he's not applying Vs, but I could be wrong in my interpretation